# Why does the same android java code shows different languages on device Nexus 7 and device Nexus 5x

Tags: android, java-native-interface, nexus-7, jexcelapi, nexus-5x

System environment: Android Studio 3.4  with Gradle plugin to version 3.4.0 and Gradle to version 5.1.1. 
I created a new project --> File --> New --> Import Sample --> Ndk --> Hello JNI. I changed in build.gradle file minSdkVersion to 22, because of my Nexus 7 can not do more. 
Then I downloaded jexcel_android.jar from https://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelandroid/ and copied the jexcel_android.jar  to ...app/libs/ 
In HelloJni.java I added some code see details.
In AndroidManifest I just added permission to write to sdcard.

– I have not changed or added anything else. I was able to install and run the app on Nexus 7 and Nexus 5x.
The created file on Nexus 7 shows the expected English letters.
The created file om Nexus 5x shows non expected Chinese letters.
Why? Normally both devices show English letters on all other apps.

Here the code i added in HelloJni.java:
String str ="";

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    /* Retrieve our TextView and set its content.
     * the text is retrieved by calling a native
     * function.
     */
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hello_jni);
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hello_textview);

    WritableWorkbook wb = createWorkbook("my.xls");
    WritableSheet sh = createSheet(wb,"mysheet", 0);
    try {
        //writeCell(0, 0,  "hi", true, sh);
        wb.write();
        wb.close();
    }
    catch (
            IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (
            WriteException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    str += "\n" +stringFromJNI();
    tv.setText( str );
}




/**
 *
 * @param wb - WritableWorkbook to create new sheet in
 * @param sheetName - name to be given to new sheet
 * @param sheetIndex - position in sheet tabs at bottom of workbook
 * @return - a new WritableSheet in given WritableWorkbook
 */
public WritableSheet createSheet(WritableWorkbook wb,
                                 String sheetName, int sheetIndex){
    //create a new WritableSheet and return it
    return wb.createSheet(sheetName, sheetIndex);
}
/**
 *
 * @param fileName - the name to give the new workbook file
 * @return - a new WritableWorkbook with the given fileName
 */
public WritableWorkbook createWorkbook(String fileName){
    //exports must use a temp file while writing to avoid memory hogging
    WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
    wbSettings.setUseTemporaryFileDuringWrite(true);
    str += wbSettings.getLocale().getLanguage();
    //Log.i("HelloJni", " wbSettings.getLocale().getLanguage()=" +wbSettings.getLocale().getLanguage());
    //get the sdcard's directory
    File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    //add on the your app's path
    File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/");
    //make them in case they're not there
    dir.mkdirs();
    //create a standard java.io.File object for the Workbook to use
    File wbfile = new File(dir,fileName);

    WritableWorkbook wb = null;

    try{
        //create a new WritableWorkbook using the java.io.File and
        //WorkbookSettings from above
        wb = Workbook.createWorkbook(wbfile,wbSettings);
    }catch(IOException ex){
        Log.e(className,ex.getStackTrace().toString());
        Log.e(className, ex.getMessage());
    }

    return wb;
}
```

The Logcat of Android Studio for Nexus 7 looks like expected. 
But in Nexus 5x I got a lot of info/error output. Approx. 5 times this stuff, everytime the same, So you see only not repeated stuff:

```
2019-04-27 21:04:25.650 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:515)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.650 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:423)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.650 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(int, android.view.ViewGroup) (LayoutInflater.java:374)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.650 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at android.view.ViewGroup android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:607)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.650 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor() (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.650 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(int) (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:466)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.650 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(int) (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.650 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at void com.example.hellojni.HelloJni.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (HelloJni.java:75)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.650 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle, android.os.PersistableBundle) (Activity.java:7009)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.650 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:7000)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.650 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1214)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.650 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2731)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.650 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2856)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.650 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.650 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1589)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.650 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:106)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.650 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:164)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.650 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6494)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.650 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.650 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at void com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (RuntimeInit.java:438)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.650 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:807)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.651 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
2019-04-27 21:04:25.651 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at void android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2341)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.651 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at void android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.651 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.651 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:334)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.651 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:647)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.651 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:790)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.651 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:730)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.651 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:863)
2019-04-27 21:04:25.651 21326-21326/com.example.hellojni I/zygote:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:824)
```

Comment: Also strange stuff: In order to get the app installed on Nexus 5x I have to incorporate the JNI part I do not really need. Without JNI I got the problem I described here:

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55859384/why-is-jexcel-android-jar-working-on-device-nexus-7-but-not-on-device-nexus-5x